# Count queries with Activate framework?

Tags: scala

Is there any simple way make count queries with Activate?

What I'm doing today is something like this:

```
transactional {    
    allWhere[NaturalPerson].size
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

```
all[NaturalPerson].size

query {
    (p: NaturalPerson) => where(p isNotNull) select(1)
}.size
```

Both has good performance, but the second one has better performance and can be used on versions after or equal 1.0-RC2.

Note that you are using allWhere without conditions. This won't compile. Use just "all" if you don't have conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the test suite that comes with the framework. Here is an example test taken from [`QuerySpecs.scala`](https://github.com/fwbrasil/activate/blob/master/activate-tests/src/test/scala/net/fwbrasil/activate/statement/query/QuerySpecs.scala):

```
"support count query" in {
  activateTest(
    (step: StepExecutor) => {
      import step.ctx._
      step {
        newEmptyActivateTestEntity
        newEmptyActivateTestEntity
      }
      step {
        query {
          (e: ActivateTestEntity) => where(e isNotNull) select (1)
        }.sum must beEqualTo(2)
      }
    }
  )
}
```